# Arduino wait for serial data from Python

Tags: python, arduino

I'm new to Arduino, and I'm trying to make a game. I'm sending the serial data with Python to the Arduino. I want to make the Arduino wait untill it recieves the serial data from Python.

My questions are:

- Why isn't the Arduino program working with serial data from Python, but it works with data from Serial Monitor?
- How can I make the program work with data from Python? (Wait untill serial data from Python, and then save the data.)

Arduino code:

```
int select;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.flush();
  while(!Serial.available()){
  }
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    select=Serial.read();
  }
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println(select);
  delay(500);

}
```

Python code:

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('COM4',9600)
ser.write(b'1235')
ser.close()
```

> Solved the problem that I don't get the serial data, but a new problem occured:
>
> The problem is that, if I get the serial data, my Arduino program jumps back to the while(!Serial.available()){} loop, and not goes to the void loop(){}.

Answer (score 0):

A new USB connection with `ser=serial.Serial('COM4',9600)` resets the Arduino. The data sent right after connection are lost because the Arduino boots.

Comment: Now I get the serial data with the Arduino, but there is one problem, when I get the data the arduino program jumps back this loop: while(!Serial.available()){}, and not to void loop(){}.

Comment: every time you invoke `serial.Serial('COM4',9600)` the Arduino resets

Answer (score 0):

Like Juraj says that resets the Arduino you should add code to wait for it to come back up

```
import serial
ser=serial.Serial('COM4',9600)
sleep(.5)
if arduino.is_open == 1:
        print("open")
ser.write(b'1235')
ser.close()
```

Comment: I have one more problem, if I get the serial data, my Arduino program jumps back to this loop: while(!Serial.available()){} , and not to the void loop(){}

Comment: But now I recieve the serial data with the Arduino!